# How to find the subgroups of the group $C(ℚ)$?

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves

Let $C$ be a fixed elliptic curve over $ℚ$. The group
$C(ℚ)$ is a finitely generated Abelian group and we have $$C(ℚ)≃ℤ^{r}⊕C(ℚ)^\mathrm{tors}$$ where $C(ℚ)^\mathrm{tors}$ is a finite abelian group (is the subgroup of elements of finite order in $C(ℚ)$).

My **question** is: How to find the subgroups of the group $C(ℚ)$? I think they have the forms: $ℤ^{m}⊕C(ℚ)^\mathrm{tors}$ where $0≤m≤r$. However, I have no idea to start

Comment: There are also subgroups $\mathbb{Z}^n\times S$ with $S\le C(\mathbb{Q})^{tors}$.

Comment: This is just a question about subgroups of finitely generated abelian groups, so my advice is to read up on those.

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Is this form determines all the subgroups?